# Interacting with MIB file for DSRC wave stack in C language Body:

Tags: protocols, snmp, net-snmp, mib, yang

I am working on a final year project where I am developing a DSRC wave stack in C language. As a part of this project, I need to implement WME of 1609.3 and interact with the MIB file to get and set the necessary parameters for the stack.

This is my first time working with a project like this, and I am not sure how to interact with the MIB file in C language. I have the MIB file in the required format, and I also have a YANG file.

Can someone provide guidance on how to interact with the MIB file in C language.